# Нужно ли обособлять "в связи с..."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Если бы пару лет назад(,) в связи с гибелью твоего брата(,) я не попросил тебя вернуться домой...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Если бы пару лет назад, **в связи с гибелью твоего брата**, я не попросил тебя вернуться домой...*

Конечно, лучше бы привести предложение полностью, но, вероятно, это придаточное условное предложение в составе СПП.

Здесь оборот обособляется прежде всего **по структурным соображениям.** Получается, что в начале предложения расположены два обстоятельства (в том числе распространенный обстоятельственный оборот), которые сложно прочитать в одну фразу.

**По семантике** второй оборот имеет значение **уточнения**, и это тоже соответствует его обособлению.